# A word for using touch to find something

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say that I dropped a pen under my couch.  I can't see it, but I know it's there somewhere, so I **reach in and _______ with my hands/fingers.**

The word "search" would work, but I'm looking for something specific to touch.  "Grasp" is close, but that's the verb for after the verb I'm looking for.

Comment: Try *feel for (the item)*.

Answer (score 4):

If **blindly** is a factor in what you're looking for, then see **grope**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grope) as

> Search blindly or uncertainly by feeling with the hands.

See [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grope) define grope:

> To feel with your hands, especially in order to find or move towards something when you cannot see easily.

Keep in mind to steer clear of its other meaning, which is, to touch someone for sexual pleasure.

There is also **scrabble**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scrabble) as

> Scratch or grope around with one's fingers to find, collect, or hold on to something.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be ***probe***:

> physically explore or examine (something) with the hands or an instrument.
>   <sub>*from [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20probe&forcedict=probe)*</sub>

I believe that *probing* generally has a connotation of a careful, thorough search.

Answer (score 0):

> To feel with your hands, especially in order to find or move towards something when you cannot see easily. — [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grope)

Best word to describe is

Groping

Comment: You need to properly attribute your quotes in the future (the same way I did here). However, you're a little late because this very answer with this very quote was already given in 2017